# Axios get request with Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, ajax, webpack, axios, babeljs

I am using Webpack and Babel and trying to create an **axios** GET request and the bundle process fails when I include the **axios** request using async function.

If I remove the async function the bundling process succeeds.

Help?

**package.json:**

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"webpack": "^4.42.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
},
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
 }
```

**Webpack.config.js:**

```
  const path = require('path');
  const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/JS/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },

  plugins: [
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
             }
         }
      ]
   }
 };
```

**index.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getResults(query) {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?q=${query}`);
    console.log(res);
};

getResults(1)
```

Comment: I smelled Jonas course here :D, on that project some dependency changed.

Comment: Only when I remove ALL Babel packages, the problem is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **transpile** the `async & await` to something that will run in a browser.

There is redundant babel packages that interfere which each other.

```
// package.json

"@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.7",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
```

```
// .babelrs

{
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Edit: added regenerator

Comment: Hey @felixmosh, I had the same issue and followed your solution. The build went through successfully, but I get an error "regeneratorRuntime is not defined" at runtime. Could you help me with how I could deal with it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, added `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`